# Extract Files from installed ISO image

Tags: linux, virtual-machine

I have the ISO image on source local dive. From STORAGE option [in Oracle VM VirtualBox], uploaded ISO image and installed LINUX system. But there are few things I need help into :

1. How can I extract packages from the uploaded ISO image on VM ware ? e.g. If I have to install "yum" server, how should I put "Packages" folder under /var/www/html to create "yum DB" under yum.repos.d ?
   [Right click on ISO image --> Packages folder can be viewed on source local drive].
2. After installation, I see CLI mode. If I try "init 5", GUI mode doesn't open. How shall I go to GUI mode ? Is there any way ?

Please advise.

Regards, ErAB

Comment: Which OS is it you installed on the VM? Is ISO image of the same OS?

Comment: it's Linux ISO image.

Comment: What flavor/distribution of Linux ? What version? If it is RPM based you can try "createrepo" command http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/RepoCreate . The quality of answer dependes on the quality of question.

Comment: it's "Linux 6 64Bit.iso" image. Well, the createrepo will work on "Packages" folder under iso image. But how will I access to it on VM ware ? On which directory ?

Comment: You can try mounting your ISO image using `mount -oloop ` command to a mount point and then locate where the RPM files are.

Comment: Even first step of the link http://yum.baseurl.org/wiki/RepoCreate says "Collect the packages together in one directory." How will extract this from ISO image that contains "Packages" folder ?

Comment: Again, I don't know if there is a Linux distribution that is named as "Linux 6"

Comment: "Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.0"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46603/discussion-between-erab-and-tuxdna)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, I assume that you have a HOST machine on which you have installed VirtualBox. Inside VirtualBox you have installed a GUEST Operating System i.e. RHEL6.

Also I believe you are able to login to the GUEST OS, although it is text-based login.

I will also assume that you have access to the ISO file from with GUEST OS. If that is not the case, you can refer to

So here is what you can do:

```
cd /path/to/rhel6.iso
mkdir /var/www/html/rhel6-repo
mount -oloop /path/to/rhel6.iso /var/www/html/rhel6-repo
```

For detailed instructions on mounting:

http://technotes.twosmallcoins.com/?tag=how-to-mount-an-iso-image

Now /var/www/html/rhel6-repo will contain the full directory structure of your ISO mounted disk. You can search for the folder which contains RPM files:

```
find /var/www/html/rhel6-repo -name "*.rpm"
```

Copy the RPM files to a separate folder and then run "createrepo".